Looking to find an old horror movie (late 90's-early 2000-ish)
The story is about a girl who used to take care of her mother, then come back with her sister (I think?) and a team to this old manor house years later (I forgot why tho). 
Obviously this house is haunted.
There are two scenes I remember in the movie: 

One where there are 2 characters in a room where there is a piano, one girl presses on some notes and then one of the strings of the piano get sliced and whip her face.
One night the protagonist was sleeping, she then hear a bang-bang on the other room beside hers, thinking it's her old mother that used to live requesting help she sleep-walk to the room only to see the door to the room bending over a ghost trying to attack her


I think you are referring to The Haunting (1999) starring Liam Neeson, Lili Taylor and Catherine Zeta-Jones. Lili Taylor plays a character who has been taking care of her mother for many years. When her mother passes away, her sister evicts her. She receives a call about doing an insomnia study at an old mansion along with a few other people (one played by Catherine Zeta-Jones). There is a scene where they play some notes on a harpsichord (I think, but maybe a piano) and a wire breaks and slices one of them across the face. It turns out that the man who built the mansion had killed many children which is why the place is haunted and the main character tries to free the spirits of the children.

It's exactly that! Thanks a lot :)

Good movie. I watched it twice.
